# Is my function correctly returning a pointer to a struct?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, function-pointers

I have a project on zybooks. And my code appears to be working properly as it can correctly highlight the edges of different images.But, zybooks is automated and it is failing my edgedetect function.[image: the description of the question][image: further information on the project]
This is my code for both functions:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<limits.h>
typedef struct _image {
    int** pixels;
    int width;
    int height;
} Image;


Image* readImage(char* filename) {
    Image *pic= malloc(sizeof(Image));
    char type[3];
    int maxvalue;
    FILE *f1=NULL;
    f1= fopen(filename,"r");
        if(f1==NULL){
            printf("Unable to read image: %s\n",filename);
             return NULL;
        }
    fscanf(f1,"%s",type);
    fscanf(f1,"%d",&pic->width);
    fscanf(f1,"%d",&pic->height);
    fscanf(f1,"%d",&maxvalue);
    pic->pixels = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * pic->height);
         for (int i = 0; i < pic->height; i++) {
            pic->pixels[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * pic->width);
         }
     for (int i = 0; i < pic->height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pic->width; j++) {
           fscanf(f1,"%d",&pic->pixels[i][j]);
        }

    }
    fclose(f1);
  return pic;


}

Image* edgeDetect(Image* img, int threshold) {
    Image *edges;
    edges=malloc(sizeof(Image));
        edges->pixels = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * img->height);
            for (int i = 0; i < img->height; i++) {
                edges->pixels[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * img->width);
            }
    edges->height = img->height;
    edges->width = img->width;
     for (int i = 0; i < img->height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img->width; j++) {
            edges->pixels[i][j]=0;
        }
     }
     for(int i=0; i< edges->height;i++){
         for(int j=0; j<edges->width; j++){
             if( i > 0 && i< (edges->height-1) && j>0 && j<(edges->width-1) ){
                if(abs(img->pixels[i][j] - img->pixels[i][j+1]) > threshold || abs(img->pixels[i][j] - img->pixels[i-1][j]) > threshold)
                     edges->pixels[i][j]=255;
             }
            }
         }
    return edges;
}

int saveImage(char* filename, Image* img) {
   FILE* f1= NULL;
    f1= fopen(filename,"w");
    if(f1==NULL){
        printf("Unable to write image: %s\n",filename);
    return 1;
    }
    fprintf(f1,"P2\n");
    fprintf(f1,"%d %d\n",img->width,img->height);
    fprintf(f1,"255\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < img->height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img->width; j++) {
           fprintf(f1,"%d ",img->pixels[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(f1,"\n");
    }
        fclose(f1);
        return 0;
}

void freeImage(Image* img) {
    for (int i = 0; i < img->height; i++) {
         free(img->pixels[i]);
}
free(img->pixels);
free(img);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if( argc !=4){
         printf("Usage: ./a.out input.pgm output.pgm threshold\n");
    return 1;
    }
    int threshold= atoi(argv[3]);
    Image *data;
    data=readImage(argv[1]);
    if (data==NULL)
        return 1;
     Image *edge;
    edge= edgeDetect(data,threshold);
    freeImage(data);
    int result= saveImage(argv[2],edge);
    if (result==1)
        return 1;
    freeImage(edge);


    return 0;
}
```

Any tip would be helpful.I know the code might be confusing as it might not follow standard formatting but this is literally my first coding class.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: This looks like it leaks memory since you never `free` anything, but it does return pointers to allocated memory.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the header files: `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`

Comment: I did not post the full code. I will do that now

Comment: You understand that the *raster* sample (R, G, B) in a PPM image can be either ASCII text (type `"P3"`) or Raw - binary (type `"P6"`)  where if `maxcolor < 256` each sample is 1-bytes, otherwise each sample is 2-bytes. Are you limited to Basic `"P3"` image types?

Comment: yes. I am limited to "P3"

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
Image *pic= malloc(sizeof(Image));
```

Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. If not successful, call

```
perror( "your error message" );
```

to output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

regarding:

```
printf("Unable to read image: %s\n",filename);
```

Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`. Suggest using:

```
fprintf( stderr, "Unable to read image: %s\n %s\n", filename, strerror( errno ) );
```

When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, like `fscanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. Note: That family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers.

regarding:

```
fscanf(f1,"%s",type);
```

1. any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.
2. when using `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS
   modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer to
   avoid any buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior, because those 'input format conversion' specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.

regarding:

```
pic->pixels = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * pic->height);
```

in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer. Casting just clutters the code. Suggest removing the cast.

for ease of readability and understanding:

1. separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` should be separated via a single blank line.
2. consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'.
   Unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level
   be 4 spaces
3. insert appropriate horizontal space: inside parens,
   inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons,
   around C operators

the function: `malloc()` expects the parameter to be of type `size_t`, however; statements like:

```
edges->pixels = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * img->height);
```

are being passed a `int` as part of the parameter. ( I.E. the `img->height` ) This results in an implicit conversion between `int` and `size_t` which is 'usually' harmless, but is still a risky conversion.

Comment: Preferred `edges->pixels = malloc (img->height * sizeof *edges->pixels);` See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) and using the dereferenced pointer to set *type-size* ensures you are never wrong.

Comment: @user3629249 I have corrected my code based on your answer but zybooks still fails my edgedetect and main functions. Can you see if there is any error or bug cause I can't seem to figure it out?